# Matlab Unused input notation details

Tags: matlab, operators

[Matlab R2009b introduced a new "operator"](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2009/09/11/matlab-release-2009b-best-new-feature-or/) - ~ - to symbolize an unused function output or input.  I have detailed question about that implementation.  (Calling all [@Loren](https://stackoverflow.com/users/113700/loren) s.)

What does the function see for the value of an unused input parameter?

i.e. if my function is defined as

```
myfunc(argOne, argTwo, argThree)
```

and it’s called like this:

```
myfunc('arg', ~, 'arg')
```

Is nargin 2, or 3?
Is argTwo undefined or empty or something else?

Thanks

Comment: Oh boy their syntax is heading for a dead end.

Comment: If you have MATLAB available I would advise to write a small test function to find it out!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `~` syntax is only applicable to the inputs of the function *definition*, not the inputs of the function *call* (as discussed on [this documentation page](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/bresuxt-1.html#br67dkp-1)). In other words, *this* is OK:

```
function myfunc(argOne, ~, argThree)  %# Will do nothing with the second input
  %# Do stuff here
end
```

but *this* is not:

```
myfunc('arg', ~, 'arg');  %# Error city ;)
```

So, when calling a function, you can only use `~` on the *left-hand side*:

```
[~, I] = sort([2 4 1 2 5 3]);  %# Sort the vector and keep only the index
```

Comment: The ~ can be used in a function _call_ if it's on the LHS. E.g. "[~,~,x] = junk(1)" works. Nargout is the same as if regular variables had been used.

Comment: @Andrew: Noted, and thanks. I rephrased so that hopefully it is clearer now.